# Voltage changing

Tags: voltage, resistors

I'm finding a problem with changing voltage. I will explain by example:

Let's assume I have a 20 V voltage source connected to specific circuit, and that circuit has resistor with a 5 V drop. All fine for me.

Now let's assume I changed the value of the voltage source to 10 V, then the drop on the same resistor that I explained before is 2 V.

*Where has the previous 5 V gone?* Now my resistor's drop was 5 V and changed to 2 V, what does it mean changed? Is it magic that the previous value of the resistor's drop is gone since I changed the source voltage?!

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is magic.

Comment: Can you explain to me why it is that 4x5=20 but when I change the 4 to a 2 the sum is now 2x5=10. If you can explain that, then apply that same logic to your question.

Comment: Show a schematic to explain what you're talking about as I have no clue what you mean.

Comment: There is a CircuitLab schematic button on the editor toolbar. It'd very easy to use and you don't need an account. Hit the edit link below your question ...

Comment: but here we are dealing with physical devices !! not abstraction!

Comment: Tony, models *model* the physical devices. No magic. do the math correctly. stop acting as if something else is wrong. You're not doing the things right. This is really basic stuff.

Comment: It's just Ohms Law. V=IR. If you change the value of one of the terms, then the others have to change too.

Comment: From the comments on MCG's [answer below](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/444527/148777), I think @Tony.M is trying to ask about the physical changes that occur. Not how to determine what the new voltage drop is, but what happened to the resistor and the electrons to make it so. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

Ohm's Law. That is the simple answer. V = I*R. If the source voltage is lower, the current in the circuit is lower. If the current of the circuit is lower, the voltage drop over a fixed resistor will be lower.

Study Ohm's Law and you will see that this is not the work of a wizard, and you are not finding a problem. You are simply observing what should be happening.

Let us see an example....

[image]

Here we have a circuit as you described. There is a source voltage of 20V, and a fixed resistor with a 5V drop. Let's do the math.....

I = V/R = 20/20 = 1A. as there is a total of 20 Ohms in the circuit, and it is a series circuit, we must include both resistors in the calculations. So, we calculated 1A, and you can see, there is indeed 1A.

V = I*R = 1*5 = 5V. As you can see, there is indeed a 5V drop over the resistor.

Now let's change the source voltage to 10V, and see what we expect.....

I = V/R = 10/20 = 0.5A.

V = I*R = 0.5*5 = 2.5V.

Ok, so just by changing the source voltage, the math tells us that there is now only 0.5A in the circuit, and the voltage drop over the **same** resistor should be 2.5V. Let's see if this works:

[image]

It does!

You see? It hasn't magically disappeared, you have changed the values of the circuit, therefore you change the maths, and change the result. Nothing magic is going on at all, it hasn't 'disappeared', you just changed the source which has a knock on effect for the rest of the circuit.

Comment: but you seem that you didn't understand me, lets assume it was 5v, now after changing source voltage we got drop resistor 2v. where does the 5v gone? lets assume once again if I assign in Ohm's Law V=20v, I get for instance current 2A, I changed the V to 35v, now I get instance current 4A, where did the previous 2A gone? I know I changed the V , but where the previous current went, gone?! is it magic?!!

Comment: I understood you perfectly. Do the math. It is not magic

Comment: I appreciate your effort. what does it mean "DO THE MATH"? is the previous data smashed?! here you don't have math , you've drop on devices!!!

Comment: You have changed the numbers in the equation..... The source voltage is part of the equation. If you change that, why are you expecting to still get the same drop? The schematic editor doesn't seem to be working for me at the moment. But I will do an example for you if you bear with me

Comment: I know math! but here the case is different because we are dealing with physical devices !! so in math you can change because it's abstraction. but on physical devices ..what's going ?! gone?! magic?!

Comment: Are you convinced with changed as something gone?! it's not good answer for

Comment: Tony, really, MCG is right. You're not doing the math correctly, no matter how much you insist you do. Don't be like that.

Comment: @Tony.M I have added an example showing simulated results, and the accompanying math involved. As you can see, there is no magic. If you follow Ohm's Law and do the math, it works out *exactly* as you are seeing

Comment: Hi @MGG , I appreciate !!! but what's confusing me where did the previous amount disappeared ?!

Comment: @Tony.M I hope it now make sense to you now that you have seen a simulation, and the math involved?

Comment: here after you changed the voltage .. I'm fine that new answers/voltages we got. but my problem because we are dealing with devices, as where the previous voltage before changing, gone after changing?! or magic?!  .. my problem isn't that the answer changed ! , my problem where did the previous voltage gone after changing ?!

Comment: @Tony.M you change the input. That is where the voltage "went" you took it away when you changed the input.

Comment: @Tony.M I don't understand what you mean? The simulation is simulating real devices. The voltage over the resistor hasn't 'gone' anywhere. You have changed the source so it doesn't have the resources available to maintain a 5V drop. You **need** to stop thinking about it as 'disappearing' because it is not. You are not measuring a 5V resistor, you are measuring a 5V **drop** across the resistor. It needs 20V to maintain the current needed for that drop. You have removed the voltage needed to maintain the current, therefore the drop decreases. It is really very, very simple stuff

Comment: I mean like this, I was having 5v source voltage so I get drop on the resistor 2v, I changed source voltage to 10v, I get drop on the resistor 7v, now where did 2v on the resistor gone? is after changing the source voltage to 10v, then the source voltage increase the voltage on the resistor (increase the amount than the previous) or he first decrease the amount on the resistor to zero and then he put new drop voltage on the resistor?!!!

Comment: @Tony.M I don't know how I can make this any clearer. If you change the source voltage you change the current in the circuit. When the current changes, the voltage drop changes. That is that. It doesn't disappear, there is no magic. The rest of the voltage you are missing will be dropped over the other resistor in the circuit. In my example, 5V is dropped over R1, so 15V will be dropped over R2. When the source is changed, 2.5V is dropped over R1 and 7.5V over R2. If you still can't get it, I don't know how much more I can help. I have given examples and math proving it works.

Comment: @MGG I appreciate your answer, but once again, if the source voltage was 5v, I get drop resistor 2v. now if I changed the source voltage to 10v, my question is, the previous drop of the resistor first goes to zero and then adapt itself to the new source voltage or it's increase/decrease from its drop adapt to the new source voltage?

Comment: we learned in school, that voltage is about electrons goes from/to the resistor .. so I'm asking if after changing the source voltage the electrons goes decrease/increase from/to the resistor

Comment: @Tony.M It changes *with* the change in source voltage.

Comment: but I wanted to know how it changes .. I mean is electrons go to grand and then the source voltage would assign the new drop on the resistor? that's my problem .. if it changes .. how does it change

Answer (score 1):

So, Ohm's law is one of the two things here: V=IR.

The other thing here is algebra. Applying that to V=IR, we can have I=V/R and R=V/I.

In your first example, you have a potential divider. You put in 20V across two resistors, one of which gives you a drop of 5V, so you have 15V on the other. For example these could be a 5 Ohmn and 15 Ohm pair of resistors, and would result in a current of 1A. If you change the input voltage to 10, you now have 10V across a 5R and a 15R, giving you a voltage drop of 2.5 and 7.5 respectively, and a current of 0.5.

Your 5V was changed when you changed the input voltage.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it's better to define some things.

Voltage is the measure of potential energy stored at a point in electrical form. As others have mentioned, Voltage is directly related to current and resistance.

When you change the source from 20V to 10V you change the potential energy of the source which affects the rest of the connected circuit. The change from a higher potential to a lower potential travels along a wire almost like a wave, or ripple, in a pool. This change is very quick. So quick, in fact, that it's almost instant.

In your example, the '3V' don't go anywhere, because 'Voltage' does not travel. It is a value that represents the potential energy at that particular point in space.

Since the potential at the source dropped, so does the potential accross the different points on the wire. The energy that was already stored, on the otherhand, continues to 'flow' through the wire. 'Less' energy flows now that the potential is lower, but the 'original energy' still is traveling through the wire until it reaches the 'end.'

Comment: I appreciate your answer, you mean by instant .. we can't notice the re-change (switch between two values of changing) ?

Comment: By instant I mean very close to the speed of light.